# Error 401: Request is missing required authentication credential

Tags: google-api-php-client, androidpublisher

We are working with play customapp api but at the final stage below is the error using PHP api client libraries
i am seeing the same issue Error 401: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project., unauthorized can anyone help us to fix this issue tried all possible ways